# Coding Bat, Recursion-2, groupSum

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

So, after finishing Recursion-1, I want to do Recursion-2. However, the first question has already stumped me because I cannot understand what it is asking. The question reads like this:

"Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, such that the group sums to the given target? This is a classic backtracking recursion problem. Once you understand the recursive backtracking strategy in this problem, you can use the same pattern for many problems to search a space of choices. Rather than looking at the whole array, our convention is to consider the part of the array starting at index start and continuing to the end of the array. The caller can specify the whole array simply by passing start as 0. No loops are needed -- the recursive calls progress down the array."

This is the starting code:

```
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) 
{
}
```

What I did first was I copied the solution given by coding bat in order to have a idea of what's going on. Looking at the answers, I got even more confused. I cannot understand how

```
groupSum(1, [2, 4, 8], 8) → true
```

but

```
groupSum(1, [2, 4, 8], 2) → false
```

Comment: Let me explain recursion to you, if you don't understand recursion please start reading this sentence from the beginning. Note that `0` in the **first** term of your second example (`groupSum(0, [2, 4, 8], 2)`) *should* be `true`. Clearly eight is equal to eight, so we can see why there is sum of terms that equals eight in the first example (given terms four and eight). In the second example we only have terms four and eight, neither can sum to two.

Comment: I understand a bit about recursion because I managed to finish recursion-1, which had 30 problems and I manged to solve 28 of them without any external help. However, I don't understand this question because I think, from my understanding of the question, groupSum(1, [2, 4, 8], 2) should return true because on of the element of the array is already 2. However, I have a flaw in my understanding because according to Coding Bat itself, it should return false.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't read your full answer.

Comment: Oh, I finally got it! So, the start is the starting index. So, in my second example, I start at index 1. Since 4 and 8 clearly cannot make 2, it returned false.

Comment: Correct. *The caller can specify the whole array simply by passing start as 0.* One is not zero.

Comment: Okay, but how does groupSum(0, [10, 2, 2, 5], 9) → true? Are we subtracting elements as well?

Comment: Also, what would be your solution to this question?

Comment: 2+2+5=9. You have to consider the sum(s) of the terms, not just the terms themselves. I would probably **not** solve this recursively.